# What is wrong with this \foreach statement?

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, pgffor

The code below

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % draw two line segments
  \draw (0,0) node [below] {$s_i$} -- (2,0) node [below] {$c_i$};
  \draw (1,-2) node [below] {$s_j$} -- (3, -2) node [below] {$c_j$};

  % this works well
  \draw ($(0,0)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(0,0)-(0,2pt)$);
  % the following \foreach does not work
  \foreach \point in {(0,0), (2,0), (1,-2), (3,-2)}
    \draw ($\point+(0,2pt)$) -- ($\point-(0,2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces the `Runaway argument` error:

```
Runaway argument?
\point +(0,2pt)$) -- ($\point -(0,2pt)$);\pgffor@endhook \ifx \pgffor@assign@af
ter@code \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \tikz@cc@parse@factor was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.18 

I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
```

The reason may be trivial. But, I failed to find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements in the `\foreach` list are specified as `(0,0)` etc, which is nothing what the Ti*k*z `calc` library parser recognizes as being real coordinates or node names later on, it will report the `run-away-argument` error (Clarified this according to the comment by @PaulGaborit below)

*One* possible solution is to use `{0,0}` (to keep the `,` together with the numbers as one element and say `\draw $(point)-(0,2pt)$)--...`.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % draw two line segments
  \draw (0,0) node [below] {$s_i$} -- (2,0) node [below] {$c_i$};
  \draw (1,-2) node [below] {$s_j$} -- (3, -2) node [below] {$c_j$};

  % this works well
  \draw ($(0,0)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(0,0)-(0,2pt)$);
  % the following \foreach does work 
  \foreach \point in {{0,0}, {2,0}, {1,-2}, {3,-2}} {
    \draw ($(\point)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(\point)-(0,2pt)$);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your solution works... but the initial problem is not related to `\foreach` but to the `calc` library (and its  `\tikz@cc@parse@factor` macro).

Comment: @PaulGaborit: Thanks, I've used your comment and incorporated into the solution, referring to your comment. It is clearer to me now as well.

Answer (score 4):

Or also

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % draw two line segments
  \draw (0,0) node [below] {$s_i$} -- (2,0) node [below] {$c_i$};
  \draw (1,-2) node [below] {$s_j$} -- (3, -2) node [below] {$c_j$};

  % this works well
  \draw ($(0,0)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(0,0)-(0,2pt)$);
  % the following \foreach does work
  \foreach \x/\y in {0/0,2/0,1/-2,3/-2}
    \draw ($(\x,\y)+(0,2pt)$) -- ($(\x,\y)-(0,2pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Separating the coordinates could be useful if, in the future, it happens you would like to do something like this:

```
  \foreach \x in {...}
      \foreach \y in {...}
          ... some command with (\x,\y) ...;
```

Comment: By editing the `not` out of my answer I can retype my words again that has been dropped by your edit :-(

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Sorry, we did it as the same istant!

Comment: Well, it was not really necessary at all, that's why I almost never edit answers... I leave a comment about a typo or error etc. then.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Next time I'll wait a bit... or leave a comment